# Is there a way to transfer data from database in one Netezza appliance to database in anothernetezza appliance?

Tags: netezza

I want to create an exact copy of a database from one Netezza appliance to another.  Short of writing an ODBC program, are there any utilities that I can use to achieve this?

Is it possible to used nzbackup/restore to stream data to stdout/stdin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stream data between the appliances rather than land a backup file, use nz_migrate.

Comment: Can you provide a link and possibly more details?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use a combinatio of the nzbackup and the nzrestore CLI tools. Check the Netezza Database Users Guide. Also :

```
 which nz_migrate
 locate nz_migrate
 nz_migrate -shost 37.101.62.161 -thost 84.128.61.163 -sdb source_db_name \
 -tdb tg_db_name -tuser user -tpassword secret_pass -format binary \
 -t table1 table2 table3 tablen -genStats Express \
 -CreateTargetTable YES -truncateTargetTable YES
```